# How to set default name to window after changing?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a window named "Skylines", and I want to get coordinates of mouse click inside this window. I want to write them on the window's header, but I don't understand how to change the name of the window after mouse button is released.

Now I have done this:

```
void mouseOnSkylines(int evt, int x, int y, int flags, void* param)
{
    char sWindowName[100];
    HWND hWnd, hPar;

    switch(evt)
    {
    case CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        hWnd = (HWND)cvGetWindowHandle("Skylines");
        hPar = GetParent(hWnd);

        sprintf(sWindowName, "(%d, %d)", x, y);
        SetWindowText(hPar, sWindowName);
        break;
    case CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        hWnd = (HWND)cvGetWindowHandle("Skylines");
        hPar = GetParent(hWnd);

        sprintf(sWindowName, "Skylines");
        SetWindowText(hPar, sWindowName);
    }
}
```

How it could be done better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In windows, you can set and reset the title of the OpenCV window as follows:

```
#include<afxwin.h>
void mouse(int _event, int x, int y,int flags, void* param)
{
    static char old_name[256];

    if(_event==CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN)
    {
        char* old_name_ptr = (char*)param;
        memcpy(old_name,old_name_ptr,256);

        char new_name[256];
        sprintf(new_name,"%d, %d\0",x,y);

        HWND hWnd = (HWND)cvGetWindowHandle(old_name);
        CWnd *wnd = CWnd::FromHandle(hWnd);
        CWnd *wndP = wnd->GetParent();
        wndP->SetWindowText(new_name);      
    }

    if(_event==CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP)
    {
        char* old_name_ptr = (char*)param;
        HWND hWnd = (HWND)cvGetWindowHandle(old_name_ptr);
        CWnd *wnd = CWnd::FromHandle(hWnd);
        CWnd *wndP = wnd->GetParent();
        wndP->SetWindowText(old_name);      
    }
}
```

## In the main function:

```
IplImage* img = cvLoadImage(path);

char winTitle[256] = "Skylines";

cvNamedWindow(winTitle);
cvSetMouseCallback(winTitle,mouse,winTitle);
cvShowImage(winTitle,img);
cvWaitKey();
```

Comment: thank you, I've already got this idea and this seems to be the closest thing to one I want. But I wondered if there was a method to get current window name or something.